# Upper bound on the expected number of steps to reach 1 from n

Tags: expected-value, random-walk

Suppose a particle is moving in discrete steps. When it is at position $n\ge1$, it takes a step of size $X_n$, and moves to $n-X_n$, where $X_n$ is a random variable taking values in $\{i\in\Bbb{Z}\mid i\le n-1\}$. Suppose there is a non-decreasing function $g:\Bbb{R}^+\to\Bbb{R}^+$ (where $\Bbb{R}^+$ is the set of positive reals). All that we know about the distribution of $X_n$, is that $\Bbb{E}[X_n]\ge g(n)$.

**Let $T_n$ be the number of steps the particle takes to reach $1$ (for the first time). How can I calculate an upper bound on $\Bbb{E}[T_n]$ in terms of $g(n)$?**

*I have solved the problem for a much simpler case, where $X_n$ could only take the values $1,2,\cdots,n-1$. This simpler version can be easily solved via induction, and it turns out

$$\Bbb{E}[T_n]\le\int_1^n\frac{dx}{g(x)}$$*

This can be proved via induction. Suppose the statement is true for all integers $< n$. When the particle is at $n$, it takes the first step to go to $n-X_n$, so we have
\begin{align*}
\Bbb{E}[T_n]&=1+\Bbb{E}[T_{n-X_n}]\\
&\le 1+\Bbb{E}\left[\int_1^{n-X_n}\frac{dy}{g(y)}\right]\\
&\le 1+\Bbb{E}\left[\int_1^{n}\frac{dy}{g(y)}-\int_{n-X_n}^{n}\frac{dy}{g(y)}\right]\\
&\le 1+\int_1^{n}\frac{dy}{g(y)}-\frac{1}{g(n)}\Bbb{E}\left[\int_{n-X_n}^{n}dy\right]\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [\text{as}\ g(n)\ \text{is non-decreasing.}]\\
&\le1+\int_1^n\frac{dy}{g(y)}-\frac{\Bbb{E}[X_n]}{g(n)}\\
&\le \int_1^n\frac{dy}{g(y)}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [\text{as}\ \Bbb{E}[X_n]\ge g(n)]
\end{align*}

How do I solve it for the more general case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you really mean that $n_0=n$ and $n_{k+1}=n_k-X_{n_k}.$ Also is $X_n\geq 0?$ Or even $\geq 1?$

Comment: I have already mentioned the range of values $X_n$ can take, all integers (including negative ones) less than or equal to $n-1$

Comment: Please describe in some detail how to **calculate** in the much simpler case the (exact) value for $\Bbb E[T_n]$. (The question, as it is now, wants the exact value of $\Bbb E[T_n]$ in the case when the path of the particle can have "raises"...)

Comment: @dan_fulea I have added my solution for the simpler case. See if it helps.

Comment: The added information still **does not calculate** $\Bbb E[T_n]$, it provides only a rough upper bound. The question, as stated in a bold face font wants explicitly to calculate it. You emphasized the question, i did it for the word **calculate** too in the above comment. It is hard to formulate the "appropriate question" regarding only an upper bound issue, since details of the purpose of usage are needed and details of the "kind of bound" may have to be elaborated. So a potential answerer has two problems...

Comment: @dan_fulea I actually want an upper bound...in fact I want to show if the statement, $\Bbb{E}[T_n]\le\int_1^n\frac{dx}{g(x)}$, (which is proved for the simpler case), also holds for the general case.